# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "login" does not exist Position: 17

Tags: java, postgresql

here i am trying to connect my java program with postgresql, i tried a lot, but always i having this error that relation is dosn't exixt, i created that data base in postgresql using GUI, and its created successfully, so please help me .
here is my code

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/medical","postgres","toor");
//its fine till here
    stt2.executeUpdate("select uid from login");
//its showing error after executing above code
```

Thanks

Comment: The connection to the database is fine. What is not fine is that there is no `login` table in the database.